# ElasticSearch search_after with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

```
GET twitter/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    },
    "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
    "sort": [
        {"date": "asc"},
        {"tie_breaker_id": "asc"}
    ]
```

How to write search_after (elasticsearch) code in nodejs

Comment: it's definitely possible to do it in Node.js, but maybe show what you have tried so far

Comment: elasticClient.search({
                            index: elasticsearch_setup.index,
                            type: elasticsearch_setup.type,
                            from: from + offset,
                            size: (offset + from + page) > limit ? (limit - offset - from) : page,
                            body: queryBody,
                            search_after : [1000]
                        }, callback);

Comment: above is code in nodejs

Answer (score 3):

The `search_after` key goes into the body:

```
queryBody.search_after = [1000];

elasticClient.search({ 
    index: elasticsearch_setup.index, 
    type: elasticsearch_setup.type, 
    size: page, 
    body: queryBody
}, callback);
```

Also note that when using `search_after` you don't need to also iterate with from/size.

Comment: But make sure to just specify `size: page` and no `from`

Comment: No from parameter, indeed

Comment: Where come from `elasticClient` ?